# regex_replace function works differently

Tags: visual-c++

i am using regular expression in one of the function in VC++. here is my code file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<regex>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
void test_regex_search(const std::string& input)
{   
    std::cout << " Initial string = " << input <<endl;
    std::regex rgx("(^|\\W)\\d+([a-zA-Z]*)?[\\\-\\\\]?(\\d*)([a-zA-Z]*)?"); 
        std::smatch match;
    char start[200] = {0};
    std::string repalcewith("");
        if (std::regex_search(input.begin(), input.end(), match, rgx))
        {
        std::cout << "match[0] = " << match[0]<< '\n';
        std::cout << "match[1] = " << match[1] << '\n';     
    }
        else
        std::cout << "No match\n";  
    std::regex_replace(&start[0],input.begin(),input.end(),rgx,repalcewith);
    std::cout << "final string = "<<start << endl;
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{       
    test_regex_search("HIGH STREET 4323HTY  KM3.5 WINES ");
    return 0;
}
```

after execution,the output is appearing like : 
final string = HIGH STREET KM3 WINES

in this particular case for word "KM3.5" why final string is coming as "KM3" whereas my regular expression is not recognizing "."? is it treating "." as space or what could be the appropriate reason for this reason.
Thanks in advance
Shashank

Answer (score 0):

Dot `.` matches `\W` at the beginning of your regular expression. You might want to use `\b` in place of `(^|\W)`

Comment: Thanks for reply.My requirement is to remove complete word if it start with number and it need to be done by regular expression only. in particular case when expression encounters "KM3.5" it should hold this complete word since it is starting with a character. whereas current behavior is converting it to "KM3" which is different from my expectation.   I went through your suggestion but if i replace "^|\\W"with "\\b", the result of "KM3.5" is "KM3." which is again a problem for me.

Comment: Define "word". `\W` class doesn't consider `.` to be a word character. If your definition of "word" is different from `[A-Za-z0-9_]+`, then you can't use `\W` but must spell non-word characters (according to your definition) explicitly.